# Function to determine if Email is typed correctly

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm in the process of learning ColdFusion and am trying to do some email validation in my project. Is there a function to check whether an email address is typed correctly?

Comment: Your question really isn't clear at all, if you'd like an answer please try rephrasing the question and showing what you've tried already, and then hopefully someone here can help you.

Comment: Sorry Simon: it's pretty clear... he's asking if there's a way to validate an email address. Although, yes, they're showing a distinct lack of having done their own work first. Even like "looking at the docs" :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`IsValid()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsValid) function, which returns 'YES' if an email is valid and 'NO' otherwise. The syntax is:

```
IsValid("email", "your.email@to.check")
```

Comment: It's actually pretty poor at doing the job it claims it does: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/07/both-coldfusion-and-railo-make-pigs-ear.html. So tread with caution when using it. It's OK for fairly superficial validation though (which'll cover 99% of situations, I guess)